# Performance difference between single large Application instance vs multiple small Application Instance in Netweaver

Tags: sap

Can anyone please comment on the performance impact of having a single large application server instance vs multiple small application server instance in SAP Netweaver on a single machine.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a situation when you need to build a server with SQL Server used by multiple client applications. Here are two options to consider.

- Single instance that host ALL the databases
- Multiple instances with each having subset of the databases.

We`ve created a table with comparison of these two options.

***Comparison of single instance to multiple instances SQL Server installation***

**Single instance is Better for**

- Memory usage
- TempDB disk usage
- CPU usage
- IO
- Ease of administration
- Overall performance
- Cost of licensing
- Monitoring

**Multiple instances is Better for**

- Separate Security between
- databases and applications
- SLA differences
- Multiple test and dev environments

**Conclusion**
From the table above we can see that having multiple instances of SQL Server on a single server could be beneficial only in a specific cases when you need a great degree of isolation for the environment, otherwise consider using single instance installation.

Comment: Is this answer about multiple database instance or multiple application server instance ?